# How to filter A which has an List of entity B using JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, jpql

So I have three Entities

1. Company:

```
class Company{
         List<City> cities;
         List<Employ> employs;
}
```

2. City:

```
class City{
        long id;
        String name;
}
```

3. Employ:

```
class Employ{
        long id;
        String name;
}
```

Now I have to filter out the Companies which has employ.name = x and has city.name = y,

How do I do that using pure form of any JPQL or MySQL would be fine,

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `JPQL` query

```
 select c from Company c  
 where 
     not exists(select 1 from c.employs emp where emp.name=:name) and 
     not exists(select 1 from c.cities city where city.name=:cityName)
```

Comment: This will give you the companies but didn't op wanted them filter out?

Comment: @Allan WindI Edited. I misunderstood the question

Comment: I don't think that query would work at all.  As the sub-queries are not correlated, you either get all rows or none at all.

Comment: @Allan WindI The query has to work. The sub-queries are correlated by the same `Company c`

Comment: A correlated sub-query means that an expression from the outer query is used to select elements of the sub-query.  You navigate the data hierarchy, maybe that's correct but it's not relational.  It's not clear from the problem if it should be an "or" or "and' between the two queries.  My answer assumes or and yours and.

Comment: @Allan WindI **an expression from the outer query is used to select elements of the sub-query:** Jpa provider generates a native query like this `select * from company c where not exists(select 1 from employee e where c.id=e.company_id and e.name=?) and not exists(...`

Answer (score 0):

The class hierarchy doesn't mention primary and foreign keys, but you would usually model it with primary company_id in company, and for the 1:n relations the company_id foreign key on many (n) side:

```
select company_id from company
where company_id not in (
  select company_id from city where name = :x
  union
  select company_id from employee where name = :y
);
```

Comment: It filters out records where `employ.name = x` **OR** `city.name = y` instead of **AND**